# How to add Accept Header with text/csv in jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery

This might be a simple question but I have not yet found the way to sort it out. I would like to download csv file from server (implemented by ASP.NET Web API) by ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    accepts: "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/api/employees",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

I have put the Accepts header in jQuery ajax like above. But from fiddler, I see:

[image]

The Accepts header now turns to `Accept: undefined`. If I try to put:

```
    accepts: {
        csv: "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
    }
```

The Accepts Header now turns to: `Accept: */*`

[image]

So I guess that is the main point to make my server returns JSON object rather than CSV file.

How can I make Accepts Header in jQuery ajax correctly? and see in the fiddler should be: 
`Accept: text/csv`

I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 
        Accept : "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I don't understand why two options I gave did not work

Answer (score 5):

Although dakait's answer is correct, I'll clean it up and offer an explanation.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path',
  headers:{ 'Accept': 'text/csv',
            'Content-Type': 'text/csv' },
  ...
```

In the above example, we are explicitly setting the two headers.

I think what is happening is that jQuery has it's own logic to handle Accept and Content-Type headers, based on `accepts` (not Accept) and dataType fields.

So, if the dataType is blank, (which would be since csv is not a supported dataType), it is suppressing the Accept header even if you set the Accept header or accepts param.

It doesn't seem to be an intuitive interface, but it works well for many people. I think if the documentation were better it would cause less confusion.